# Cross-referencing specific words

Tags: cross-referencing

I would like to cross reference to specific words in a document so that when I click on a word, it will bring me to a specific place in the document; similar to a hyperlink, except the 'URL' would be within the document.

I originally tried:

`\label{}` and tried referencing it with `\ref{}`, however I believe `\label{}` needs to be within an environment or counter to work properly. So, I then tried the `hyperref` package, however I can't figure out any way to get that to make links *within* the document itself.

Is there any way to do this? Perhaps a different package?

Comment: I did a bit of quick research using texdoc.net.    First I checked the hyperref documentation about bookmarks, which then recommended the use of the bookmark package.  I checked its documentation, again using texdoc.net.  This will do what you want.  There is an example in the documentation you can run to understand how it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\hyperlink` and  `\hypertarget` of the `hyperref` package. In this MWE the link  jump to page 3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Some \hyperlink{label}{link caption}
\newpage
Some text
\newpage
The \hypertarget{label}{target caption}
\newpage
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice and simple! Now, how to get in `link caption` the page number  where `target caption` is?

Comment: @tatojo For that you can use  `\pageref{label}` and `\label{label} target caption`, but also loading `hyperref`.

Comment: that was my first choice, but when I click on pageref, it takes me several pages before the target caption.

Comment: @tatojo Because the label and the supposed target are not really ending in the same page in the PDF.  If you write ` \mbox{\label{label} x}`  or `\begin{figure} x \label{label}\end{figure}` `\pageref`  should point to the page with the target "x". But if you write  `\label{label} x` at the very end of some page, maybe only the  "x" pass to the next page. And in case of `\label{label}\begin{figure}[p] \end{figure}`, the float with the target can move several pages with respect the label.