# How to force hyperlinks refer to a piece of text and not the corresponding section in table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, links

I have a LaTeX document in which I used "hyperref" package for creating links between different parts of my document. The links are from a word to some piece of text in another section. I use the "book" document class. Links were working fine before I created the table of contents. As soon as I created toc, the links no longer point to the piece of text in target but to the corresponding section in the table of contents.

How can I keep using the table of contents and yet create links that refer directly to a piece of text in my document?

---

**Edit: A Minimum Working Example**

```latex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}

% Defining a new command for safely creating targets in the section title
\newcommand{\targetInTitle}[2]{\texorpdfstring{\protect\hypertarget{#1}{#2}}{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{\targetInTitle{section1}{Section 1}}

Here is a \hyperlink{section1}{link} which suppose to show me the title of this section on the top of page 2 but, instead, it refers me to the table of contents on page 1.

\end{document}
```

There is also a warning in dvipdfm operation,

```
$ dvipdfm test.dvi
test.dvi -> test.pdf
[1][2
xdvipdfmx:warning: Object @section1 already defined.
]
9131 bytes written
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/234949/11604

Comment: @Fran My question is very different. I'm talking about having the links to a part of the document and a separate table of contents that works on its own. I totally know how should I create links with _hyperref_ in LaTeX.

Comment: Show a small complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: The table of contents should work without problems with this approach. Otherwise add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok. I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the target twice as it is moved to the table of contents too. You could e.g. use the NoHyper environment to suppress the target in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[dvipdfm]{hyperref}
% Defining a new command for safely creating targets in the section title
\newcommand{\targetInTitle}[2]{\texorpdfstring{\protect\hypertarget{#1}{#2}}{}}

\begin{document}

\begin{NoHyper}
\tableofcontents
\end{NoHyper}
\newpage

\section{\targetInTitle{section1}{Section 1}}

Here is a \hyperlink{section1}{link} which suppose to show me the title of this section on the top of page 2 but, instead, it refers me to the table of contents on page 1.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Neat and simple. Is there any way to keep the links of the table of contents but make them separate from the links I define within the text so that both of them will refer to a section?

Comment: You can also avoid that the target ends in the toc by using `\section[Section 1]{\targetInTitle{section1}{Section 1}}`, or you can define your command to be a dummy first and redefine it after the tableofcontents and so activate the hypertarget.